# copy only the value of equal properties from one JSON to another

Tags: java, json, clone, deep-copy

There is any way to copy only the value of equal properties from one JSON to another?
For example:

json1-

```
{
  "isMultiRow": true,
  "name": "Donny",
  "description": "Donnyboy"
}
```

json2-

```
{
  "isMultiRow": false,
  "name": "Jonny",
  "description": "Jonny boy"
  "age": "old"
  "radius":"big"
}
```

if I do something like `json1.copy(json2)` I'll get at json1 -

```
{
  "isMultiRow": false,
  "name": "Jonny",
  "description": "Jonny boy"
}
```

`age` and `radius` won't appear because they don't exist in json1.

Comment: so these are strings or any kind of json representation object?

Comment: iterate thorough the properties in json1, look them up in json2 and copy the value if found.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: What if json1 has a field not in json2?

Comment: @Blackstar - please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write a custom method that accepts 2 JSONObject and a list of fields that needs to be copied from one src JSONObject to dest JSONObject.

```
private static void copy(JSONObject dest, JSONObject src, List<String> fields) {
    for (String key : fields) {
        dest.put(key, src.get(key));
    }
}
```

Or you can have your own custom class that extends JSONObject and have a new method copy that accepts another JSON and copies field by field.

```
public class JSON extends JSONObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void copy(JSON other) {
        // implement copy logic by iterating over keySet etc
    }
}
```

`NOTE:` If your JSON has simple key-values then above will be very simple implementation, if your JSON string has complex objects, arrays etc then you would have add handling for each of those types and do a deep copy/override from src to dest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the type of your JSON object implements `Map`, you can do this:

```
json1.replaceAll(json2::getOrDefault);
```

This will replace fields in `json1` with their corresponding values from `json2`. If `json2` doesn't have a given field, it will be left as is.